# WLAN certificate on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch

For accessing the WirelessNetwork (WLAN) in my university, I need to install a certificate on my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu Touch 15.04.

Within the link below my university provides a script for automatic installation of the certificate. But the script works just on my UbuntuDesktop. On my Nexus 4 I get the error 'Permission Denied'Denied' (of course I used sudo)of

Can anybody help me to execute the script or to install theof manually?

Link: 
http://www.fh-kiel.de/fileadmin/data/Zentrale_IT/WLANeduroam/linux/2014-05-eduroam-linux-Fachhochschule_Kiel-Fachhochschule_Kiel.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the big delay. I figured out how to get it work, here is the solution:

On [this](http://www.fh-kiel.de/index.php?id=9715) page, all parameters for WLAN-Setup are listed. If I just connect to the WLAN and select in den Setup-Screen on the UbuntuPhone 'WPA2 Enterprise / AES' as encryption,  then all the other parameters can be set. Even the certificate can be selected by the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

[man update-ca-certificates:](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

`update-ca-certificates  is  a  program  that  updates   the   directory
/etc/ssl/certs to hold SSL certificates and generates certificates.crt,
a concatenated single-file list of certificates.
It reads the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf. Each line gives a pathname
of  a  CA  certificate  under /usr/share/ca-certificates that should be
trusted.  Lines that begin with "#" are comment lines and thus ignored.
Lines  that  begin with "!" are deselected, causing the deactivation of
the CA certificate in question.
Furthermore   all   certificates   found   below   /usr/local/share/ca-
certificates are also included as implicitly trusted.`
From the above, I would infer that the preferred way to get local certificate files into the trusted store is to put them into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, and then run update-ca-certificates. You do not need to touch /etc/ssl/certs directly.

Naming the certificates with .crt extensions seemed to be required as well.

Comment: Hey Dai Wei, thank you for your reply! I tried your solution, but it did not work. I found an other solution, see my answer. ;.-)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. On my phone, I couldn't choose the certificate. It gave me the browser and the filemanager as options but, whatever I chose,  I could not successfully add the certificate.

What worked for me, though, was getting the python script they make for Uni Siegen for Linux and executing it in the terminal.

In my case, it was over ssh because I like autocomplete but on the phone's Terminal, it will propably work as well.